# Memory Management for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

So I have recently just starting to look into memory management a little more in iOS but I am completely confused right now (probably overthinking it)...

For example, if you have an object A (a ViewController) strongly holding onto object B (An NSArray declared as strong in the header file of the view controller); When you specify the property of the NSArray to be strong does that mean the ViewController has a pointer to the NSArray? If that is true, what I don't understand is where are you explicitly saying that the view controller is a pointer to the NSArray object? Or does the "strong" keyword imply that the view controller has a pointer to the memory location where the NSArray is stored. Like for example, we state that the variable myArray is a pointer to an object of type NSArray in this line of code: @property(strong, nonatomic) NSArray *myArray; Is something like this done behind the scene for the view controller?

Comment: An object can't be deallocated until its retain count becomes zero.

Comment: The `NSArray *` part of the property states that you have a pointer to the array. The `strong` part only indicates the memory management of that pointer.

Comment: Hey rmaddy, I just realized my mistake that the NSArray would never be deallocated since it's retain count will not go down to 0.

Comment: Sure it will - when the view controller gets deallocated.

Comment: So is the view controller a pointer to the NSArray object? Since we declared the NSArray as strong in the header file?

Comment: Yea sorry that's what I meant! When the View Controller is deallocated then the NSArray will get deallocated.

Comment: The view controller has a pointer reference to the NSArray.

Comment: Hey rmaddy, sorry for the late reply... I got it now thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of a `@property` as the compiler automatically synthesizing these methods and instance variables for you:

```
@interface MyController {
    @private
    NSArray *_array;
}

- (NSArray *)array;
- (void)setArray:(NSArray *)array;
```

And the implementation of the setter is like this:

```
- (void)setArray:(NSArray *)array {
    if (array != _array) {
        _array = array; // strong means that ARC will retain the array here
    }
}
```

So your controller has (not is) a variable (`_array`) that points to an array.

Comment: @Bobby you're welcome. If my answer is what you were looking for, please mark it as the correct one. This is how the StackOverflow community works.